# Get inserted id if inserted happend by REPLACE INTO

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using `REPLACE INTO` to update the row where `mod_id` is the unique/primary key. I wanted to know the `mysql_inserted_id()` if it was inserted.

I tried this:

```
$query_2 = $DB->query('REPLACE INTO mods (mod_id, group_id, css) VALUES (0, 4585, "css string")');
$inserted_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

But I keep getting `$inserted_id` of `0` even if an insert happend.

Comment: Is mod_id your primary ?

Comment: Is mod_id AUTO_INCREMENT?

Comment: Ah thanks guys you caught it in a secon mode_id isnt auto_incrment. Ill fix that! Btw is there anyway to make a text field primary/unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, its better to use `INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. The reason being REPLACE always delete the old row optionally and then insert new row. While INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, tries to update the existing row  as far as possible (based on primary or unique keys). And you can `last_insert_id()`

Comment: Thanks cjg, my issue is that the field i want to make unique is a TINYTEXT field and Im not able to make it unique, is this possible?

Comment: The purpose of text/blob field is different and cant have unique indexes. MAke the column as VARCHAR(100) or so and you can add the index. Also making such a long string as unique wont give good performance. I would suggest to verify the uniqueness check to be in Application code and not in DB